# Is there any D&D 5e art for the Acolyte background/monster?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, npc, art

I run a lot of adventures on roll20, and I do my best to use official D&D art for my monsters to match the feel of the world I am trying to represent.

Currently, I'm doing stats for an Acolyte, but I can't find any art for it in the Monster Manual. To clarify, I am looking for art that represents the Acolyte as it appears in the Monster Manual or Player's Handbook.

**Does art for the Acolyte exist in any D&D 5e published products? If not, is there any other official Acolyte art in a D&D product?**

Feel free to provide links if the corresponding art exists on the internet!

Comment: when you say "the Acolyte," are you just talking about a PC with the Acolyte background, or is there something more-specific you've got in mind? Like the NPC stat block?

Comment: I would like to argue that both instances of Acolyte represent the same type of character. I'd assume that they are identical, so official art for either (or both, if I'm wrong) is acceptable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Turn back one page from the Acolyte Background**

The art on PH p. 125 (the first page of the **Backgrounds** section) seems to depict an acolyte. The figure carries a mace (commonly associated with clerics in D&D) is touching what appears to be a holy symbol brooch, and is wearing a white cloak.

Several similar character sketches throughout the Backgrounds section depict characters of other backgrounds.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as a single "official" acolyte appearance — an acolyte is just a low-rank or trainee priest. Use any art for a cleric that suits the specific NPC and religion you desire to portray.

Comment: This answer feels a little dismissive of the OP's interest. Official D&D art that represents an acolyte is not the same as 'a single "official" acolyte appearance.'